# mysql general error:1 errcode: 17 during checkout with onepage

Tags: mysql

I installed IWD's onepage checkout in Magento 1.7 a while ago and it seemed to work smoothly and integrate with my current template and other modules with no issues what so ever. However, a random customer had some issues regarding the checkout process and I received an email each time a certain error occurred:

> Payment transaction failed.
>   Reason
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_400_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)
>
> Checkout Type:onepage

I don't know how many times the customer tried to checkout that order but the number of emails I received are 8, each of them the same. A final time, the checkout process was successful.

The most unnerving thing about this is that I tried to replicate the error with a test checkout of my own and it didn't happen, leaving me with close to no idea what caused this, when it might happen again or how to fix it.

Comment: I wonder if this is a permissions issue or possibly storage space issue.

Comment: As far as I know there is no restricted storage space for the mysql db and the general storage space limit hasn't been reached. Regarding it being a permission issue, I don't know how to tell if it might be.

Answer (score 0):

mysql comes with the `perror` command.

```
$ perror 17
OS error code  17:  File exists
```

Whatever its trying to create or write to already exists and it doesn't like it.